# I need to delete a complete paragraph based on a word using regex using Groovy or Java

Tags: java, groovy

So the problem statement is:

> *Terms and Conditions
>
> This PURCHASE AGREEMENT (this “Agreement”) sets forth the terms and conditions that apply to all purchases of goods and services by blah from Seller by means of a purchase order (a “PO”) issued by blah to Seller. As used in this Agreement, “Seller” means the entity identified on the face of a P.....sdsdasda*

I want to match "Terms and Conditions" and delete/replace with whitespace everything till the end of string. This would include whitespace and newlines as well:
\*Terms and Conditions\n.* 
Pls help...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.replaceAll("(?s)Terms and Conditions.*", "") will do that, simply removing all that text. (?s) to make dot match across newlines.